# Can I use Z-Push in my AS3 Air for Android Games

Tags: android, actionscript-3, push-notification

on my web server I have access to z-push through my quick install panel.
I wanted to know how easy it is to use z-push in AS3 & most of all, is it possible to use z-push in my AS3 Air for Android Games?

Comment: What do you mean with z-push? I would guess https://z-push.org, but this has nothing to do with what you're talking about.

Comment: Yes, http://z-push.org/ is the one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Z-Push](https://z-push.org) is an open-source implementation of th MS ActiveSync protocol, written in PHP. It is used to connect Linux/Unix-based mail infrastructure to clients that understand the ActiveSync protocol.

Z-Push is, however, *not* a generic push notification framework. Unless you read from a mail server, and send messages to an ActiveSync-aware client, the answer to your question is most certainly “no”.